# How can I turn on BitLocker encryption on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: bitlocker, windows-phone-8

Does anyone know how to turn on BitLocker encryption on Windows Phone 8?

It's apparently [supported](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/business/security) but the details are a bit sketchy.

Comment: I appreciate this question is off topic for superuser-could a mod migrate it to the windows phone stackexchange site?

Answer (score 3):

I spoke to a contact at Microsoft, and it turns out there is no way to simply "turn on" bitlocker encryption on the device itself. You can only do it by connecting to an external service, for which there are several options:

- Traditional [Exchange ActiveSync policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123484(v=exchg.141).aspx)
- [Windows Intune](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windowsintune/explore/security.aspx)
- [System Center Configuration Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/configuration-manager-2012-capabilities.aspx)
- By subscribing to [Office365](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/) (and possibly [Outlook.com](http://outlook.com) but I've not been able to find any information on how to do this)

Comment: Can you expand on that last point? Does adding an Outlook.com account as an email account enable Bitlocker on the device automatically? Or is it more involved than that? If that works, it would certainly be the easiest route for a casual user to enable it.

Comment: I've not tested it yet myself - this was just what the Microsoft consultant said. If I can get hold of a device and find out I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Glass I've not been able to find any information on how to enable it via Outlook.com. Shame, as all the others are paid for options.

Comment: The enterprise versions of Office 365 has a setting "Require encryption on device". See [Managing Mobile Devices with Office 36](http://winsupersite.com/office-365/managing-mobile-devices-office-365)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is on topic here but from what I have seen, Bitlocker is enabled by default on Windows Phone 8 devices.  It was mentioned in some MS promo stuff I cannot seem to find.  It is mentioned in this [Windows Phone Security](http://www.wpcentral.com/microsoft-beefing-security-windows-phone-8) post.

"*Windows Phone 8 will have device encryption throughout the entire device including the OS and its applications. Designed along the same lines as Windows 7 PCs, encryption kicks in as soon as you power up the device. This system, based off of Bitlocker (but adapted for Windows Phone)"*

Comment: This page indicates that you turn it in via an Exchange ActiveSync policy http://wmpoweruser.com/interesting-wp8-encryption-only-available-in-business-setting/, other sites say on by default. Really difficult to find a conclusive answer!

Comment: I see what you are saying.  Very confusing.  I recall some early material said it would be on out of box but cannot recall if that was in a MS presentation or some written material.

Comment: It is not enabled by default. You can check if it is enabled by going to Settings --> Phone Storage.

If encryption is enabled it will say "XX GB used, encrypted". If it is not encrypted, it will simply say "XX GB used". It has to be enabled via EAS policy.